# Can I mark some code as optional while debugging in Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: debugging, visual-studio

I'm not sure how to really put my question into words so let me try to explain it with an example:

Let's say my program runs into some weird behavior at a specific action. I already find some code which is the cause of this weird behavior. When disabling this sequence I don't run into this behavior. Unfortunately, I need this code because something else is not working then.

So, what I gonna do next is figuring out why something is going different when that code excerpt is active.

In order to better understand what's going on I sometimes want to run the whole action including the 'bad code' and sometimes without. Then I can compare the outcome, for example what happens in the UI or what my function returns.

The first approach which comes to my mind is to run my program with the code enabled, do whatever I want, then stop my program, comment out the code, recompile and run again. Um... that sounds dumb. Especially if I then again need to turn on that code to see another time the other behavior, and then again turn off, and on, and off and so on.

It's not an option for me to use breakpoints and influence the statement order or to modify values so that I run or not run into if-statements, for-loops etc. Two examples:

- I debug a timing critical behavior and when I halt the program the timing changes significantly. Thus, the first breakpoint I can set must be at the end of the action. <sup>1</sup>
- I expect a tooltip or other window to appear which is 'suppressed' when focus is given to VS. Thus, I cannot use any breakpoints at all. Neither in the beginning nor at the end of the action.<sup>1</sup>

Is there any technique **in Visual Studio 2012** which allows me to mark this code to be optional and I can decide whether or not I want to run this code sequence **before I execute the action**? I think of something like `if(true|false)` on a higher level.

---

I'm not looking for a solution where I need to re-run my program several times. In that case I could still doing the simple approach of simply commenting out the code with `#if false`.

---

<sup>1</sup> Note that I, of course, may set a breakpoint when I need to look into a specific variable at a certain position (if I haven't written the value into output) but will turn off breakpoints again to run the whole action in one go.

Comment: I may be subjective, but that only 1 out of 6 answers is a valid answer to my question, I wonder why someone ventures to downvote the question **without** giving any clue. So, please feel free to comment here so that I can learn. Thank you.

Comment: Well, I did not downvote your question, but I think you are unclear about when you want to  activate / deactivate the optional code, and when not. Before starting the program in the debugger? Also when not starting it in debug mode? After starting it? Once per program execution, or in between? Does your program has an UI, and the code in stake is only run after the user presses a certain button, or is the code executed immediately after the program start? Please clarify!

Comment: I've just downvoted for the exact reason doc brown gave.  If you're not clear when you want a behaviour to occur then we can't reliably advise on how to implement it.

Comment: @JamesSnell "Is there any technique in VS ... and I can decided ... **before I execute the action**" -> That is, the program is running (in either debug or release mode, I don't care) and I want to execute my action (let's say I must click somewhere or whatever) and I know that I now want to turn on the code so I want to switch back to VS "turn on my previously implemented optional code" and the click the button. Or no, I want to deactivate. Back to VS, turn off, and then click the button. No restart, no recompile. So "before starting the program" "once per execution" etc. are not a option,...

Comment: ... because if so, I wouldn't care about "stop my program, comment out the code, recompile and run again". --- Perhaps my English is not well enough to say this in one sentence, but I read my questions several time and I think I pointed that out clearly.

Comment: @Em1: then what exactly do you think is missing in my suggested solution? As I pointed out, it will exactly do what you described here.

Answer (score 5):

In the Visual Studio debugger you can set a breakpoint right in front of your "code in question".  When the code stops at that point, you can elect to let it continue or you can right-click on any other line and select `Set Next Statement`.

It's kind of a weird option, but I've come to appreciate it.

Comment: Comes in handy more often than I'd care to admit.

Comment: No, I cannot do this as using breakpoints is **not** an option for me. By interrupting and/or giving focus to VS, it makes me impossible to see what I want to see (ex.: a tooltip which should appear will be 'suppressed'). I tried to make it clear in my question in my second-to-last paragraph.

Answer (score 5):

> I think of something like if(true|false) on a higher level.

Why "on a higher level"? Why not use exactly this?

You want a piece of code sometimes executed, sometimes not, and the switch should be changed at run time, not at compile time - this obviously leads to

```
if(condition)
{
    // code in stake
}
```

The catch here is what kind of `condition` you will use - maybe a variable you set to `true` in the release version of your code, and to `false` sometimes in your debug version. Maybe the value is taken from a configuration file, maybe from an environment variable, maybe calculated by some kind of logic in your program, whatever and whenever you like.

EDIT: you could also introduce a boolean variable in your code for `condition`, initialize it to `true` by default and change its value using the debugger whenever you like.

Comment: release/debug -> I don't have any profit. I still need to run it twice, just have to switch between release and debug instead of commenting out and rebuild. --- Configuration file -> It's even more painful as I need to implement something what I really, really don't need. It can make things even worse as it takes time and when I'm debugging a timing critical issue, this will change a lot. --- Calculated logic? No, I want to decide that I now run into that code and then not.

Comment: @Em1: you missed the point that I only gave you some examples  to show you that you can implement here any condition you want. You did not really explain what you mean by "now" - before you start the debugger? After you have started the debugger? On a breakpoint before the section? Assumed you mean "after starting the debugger", you can introduce a boolean variable here and use the debugger to change its contents between true or false before entering the code section in stake.

Comment: @Em1: Global variable, break into the debugger well before you get to the timing-critical portion of your code (since you've said you can't break into the debugger during that portion), edit the global variable.

Answer (score 5):

The only option I can think of is to add something to your UI that only appears when debugging, giving you the option to include/exclude the operations in question.

While you're at it, you might want to enable resetting the application to a "known state" from the UI as well.

Comment: Albeit not satisfying (excessive workaround for an actual tiny issue), up to now **the only viable solution**. +1 for this.

Comment: yes a lot of overhead for a one off...but it would be very useful if it's something you need frequently. I've worked on a number of projects that have a "developer tools" menu.

Answer (score 4):

[Preprocessor Directives](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ed8yd1ha.aspx) might be what you're after. They're bits of code for the *compiler* to execute, identifiable by starting with a `#` character (and stylistically, by default they don't follow the indent pattern of your code, instead always residing firmly at the left-hand edge of the editor):

```
#define INCLUDE_DODGY_CODE

public void MyMethodWithDodgyBits() {
#if INCLUDE_DODGY_CODE
    myDodgyMethod();
#endif
    myOkMethod();
}
```

In this case, if `#define INCLUDE_DODGY_CODE` was included, the `myDodgyMethod()` call will be compiled into your program. Otherwise, the call will be skipped by the compiler and will simply not exist in your binary.

Comment: note that you'll need to recompile (and rerun) if you want to switch from `dodgy` to `ok`

Comment: The nice thing about this solution is that you can create a separate project configurations.  Thus, switching modes is a matter of changing your configuration (e.g., via a dropdown in your menubar) and recompiling.  This makes it very easy to jump back and forth between versions, but tends to become rather unwieldy if abused.

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of options for debugging as you ask.

1. Visual Studio has a number of options to directly navigate through code.  You can use the `Set Next Statement` feature to move directly to a particular statement.  You can also directly edit values through the `Immediate Window` the `QuickWatch` and the tooltip that hovers over variables while debugging.
2. Visual Studio also has the ability to playback the execution history.  Take a look at [IntelliTrace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd264915.aspx) to get started.  It can be helpful when you have multiple areas of concern that are interacting and generating the error condition.
3. You can also wrap your sections of code within conditional blocks, and set the conditional variables as appropriate.  That could be while you're debugging, or you could pass parameters in through a configuration file.  Using conditional checks may be easier than manually stepping through code if there are a number of statements you wish to exclude.

Answer (score 0):

It sometimes depends on the version of VS and the language, but you can happily edit the code (to comment it out, or wrap it in a big #ifdef 0) then press alt+F10 and the compiler will recompile, relink and continue execution as if you'd never fiddled with it.

But while that works beautifully in VC++ (since VS v6 IIRC), C# can have issues - I find (with VS2010) that I cannot edit and continue in this way with functions containing any lambda (mainly linq) statements, and 64-bit code never used to do this too. Still, its worth experimenting with as its really useful sometimes.

Comment: Yeah, VS prevents me from doing so.

Answer (score 0):

I have worked on applications that have optional code used for debugging alone that should not appear in the production environment. This segment of optional code was easiest for us to control using a config file since it didn't require a re-compile to change.

Such a fix might not be the end all be all for your end result, but it might help get through it until a fix is found. If you have multiple optional sections that need to be tested in combination this style of fix could require multiple keys in the config file, which could be a downside and a pain to keep track of.

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't exactly clear, which is possibly why there are so many answers which you think are invalid. You may want to consider rewording it if no one seems able to answer the question.

With the risk of giving another non-valid answer I'll add some input on how I've dealt with the issue in the past.

The easiest way is to place any optional code within

```
#if DEBUG
    //Optional code here
#endif
```

That way, when you run in debug mode the code is implemented and when you run in release mode it's not. Switching between the two requires clicking one button.

I've also solved the same problem in a similar way with a simple flag:

```
bool runOptionalCode = false;
```

then

```
if (runOptionalCode)
{
    //Place optional code here
}
```

Again, switching between modes requires changing one word, so is a simple task. You mention this in your question but discount it for reasons that are unclear. As I said, it requires very little effort to switch between the two.

If you need to make changes between the code while it's running the best way is to use a UI item or a keystroke which modifies the flag mentioned in the example above. Depending on your application though this could be more effort than it's worth. In the past I've found that when I have a key listener already implemented as part of the project, having a couple of key strokes decide whether to run my debug (optional) code works best. In an application without key listeners I'd rather stick with one of the previous methods.